# task scheduling and PHPMailer class

Tags: php, smtp

i am using PHPMailer class to send email its work perfect however, my application requirement is such that I have to send email every hour by using task scheduling. Thats mean I have to use PHP.exe CLI. when I tried to execute from CLI my emailsender.php; its says unable to connect SMTP host.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but it might.

I had the following problem:

WAMP server. Windows computer.

I run some code and at the end send alert email (all php) using PHPMailer. If I just run the PHP file, it works fine. When I used Task Scheduler, the email doesn't work.

I think this comes from the task scheduler using a different version of PHP on my computer than that of Apache when I load the page on the server.

I got around this by using an absolute file path to the PHPMailer class. It now works fine...

Hope this helps? I'm in no way a pro at this but it worked for me!

Rich